# iPhone Vibrate While playing sound

Tags: iphone, vibration, playsound

How can I set iPhone to vibrate while playing the sound.

The code I use plays the sound firts and then vibrates or vice-versa.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Comment: Did you have success vibrating the iPhone while playing audio?

Comment: You also have to have the AudioToolbox.framework library in your build.