# Play custom sound while vibration on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iPhone application I need to play custom sound while vibration.
I have found here: http://gregheo.com/blog/simple-audio/ that I should use  AVAudioPlayer. But how can I play system sound of vibration using AVAudioPlayer? If there is another way to play custom sound and vibration together?

**Update** 
I have found that I can use AVAudioPlayer to play custom sound and Audiosession to play vibro system sound. But maybe someone can advise me a better solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846881/iphone-vibrate-while-playing-sound

Comment: It is not working. Vibration is a system sound and with AudioServices you can not play more than one sound at the same time

Comment: Try calling `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound`, with your alert sound as the parameter. According to the article that you posted a link to, that will play the sound and vibrate the device.

Answer (score 0):

This SO post seems to deal with the exact opposite of your issue so it might give you the answer you are looking for:

[How to play system sound on iOS without vibration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512709/how-to-play-system-sound-on-ios-without-vibration)